# Adding Cooldown to Event Listener with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener

In a JavaScript function, I have this code:

```
clicker1.addEventListener("click", nextImage, true);
```

The problem is that when the button with this event is clicked rapidly, it causes errors.

I need to make it so once the button is clicked there, is a delay where the click event doesn't run the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about disabling the button for a short while using `setTimeout`. In this example, the button is disabled for 2000 ms.

```js
function myFunction() {
  console.log('clicked !!');
  document.getElementById("myButton").disabled = true;
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("myButton").disabled = false;
  },2000);
}
```

```html
<button onClick="myFunction()" id="myButton">Press me</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

The pattern you are looking for is called [throttling](https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-b01cad5c8edf).

Here's an example implementation of a throttle function:

```
const throttle = (func, limit) => {
  let lastFunc
  let lastRan
  return function() {
    const context = this
    const args = arguments
    if (!lastRan) {
      func.apply(context, args)
      lastRan = Date.now()
    } else {
      clearTimeout(lastFunc)
      lastFunc = setTimeout(function() {
        if ((Date.now() - lastRan) >= limit) {
          func.apply(context, args)
          lastRan = Date.now()
        }
      }, limit - (Date.now() - lastRan))
    }
  }
}
```

The function gets the function to be throttled as an argument, along with a `limit` argument which is the interval in milliseconds until the next function call is permitted.

It returns another function which executes the provided function in the specified interval.

You use it like this:

```
clicker1.addEventListener("click", throttle(nextImage, 1000), true);
```

So now, if somebody "spam clicks" your clicker button, the `nextImage` function is only executed every second.

**Note**: If you use Lodash, you can use its own throttle implementation [_.throttle](https://lodash.com/docs#throttle).

Answer (score 2):

A simpler version of throttling, inspired by [Patrick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53930440/9783641)

```
function throttle(func, cooldownMillis) {
    let lastRan = 0;

    return function() {
        if (Date.now() - lastRan > cooldownMillis) {
            func.apply(this, arguments);
            lastRan = Date.now();
        }
    }
}
```

As in his example, use it like this:

```
clicker1.addEventListener("click", throttle(nextImage, 1000), true);
```